# I can't make a JoinColumn nullable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to create Many to Zero or One link in a Symfony/Doctrine entity. I think the following should work the trick:

```
    /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="vragenlijst_id")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GroNed\AdminBundle\Entity\WalkthroughType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vragenlijst_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $vragenlijst;
```

However: Doctrine seems to disagree with me:

```
[bhillier@devserver-2 Symfony]$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE walkthrough CHANGE vragenlijst_id vragenlijst_id INT NOT NULL;
```

I'm probably missing something stupid, but I can't see what at the moment. Has anyone got any ideas?

In case it helps:

```
[bhillier@devserver-2 Symfony]$ /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Jan 26 2016 06:31:19
[bhillier@devserver-2 Symfony]$ /opt/php-5.6/bin/php --version
PHP 5.6.17 (cli) (built: Jan 26 2016 05:36:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
[bhillier@devserver-2 Symfony]$ php app/console --version
Symfony version 2.6.13 - app/dev/debug
```

Comment: Normally this is when people use quotes by mistake `nullable="true"` but I see that's not the case here ... you don't need `@var` or `@ORM\Column` so dump those, see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks @Egg. Indeed the `@ORM\Column` was overriding the `@JoinColumn`, causing all my problems!

Comment: Don't forget allowing your setter accepting null as well: setVragenlijst($vragenlijst = null)

Comment: You're welcome @BenHillier; I've repeated this as a posted answer to help anyone else coming here in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to delete the `@var` and `@ORM\Column` annotations, these aren't required when using associations.

Answer (score 2):

According to your annotations, you're telling `Doctrine` to create a column called `vragenlijst_id` and you don't say anything about it's nullable attribute. You're doing so with the annotation:

```
 @ORM\Column(name="vragenlijst_id")
```

The right annotations would be:

```
  /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GroNed\AdminBundle\Entity\WalkthroughType")
    */
   private $vragenlijst;
```

Comment: Hi Oscar! Both yours' and Egg's answers were correct, but @Egg has already put me on the right track in his comments, so I've credited him with the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BenHillier : glad to have helped!